# The use of probable and may is confusing

Tags: verbal-noun

I am completely confused about the combination of this two words.

"she **probably may** have a form"
"she **may probably** use it"

The combination of this two words are quite confusing. I think one should be used instead.

Comment: You are correct. One of them is enough, though you might hear native speakers saying "may probably". Redundancy is not a problem in natural language. It reinforces meaning.

Comment: "She may use it" gives no information about the speaker's opinion as to the probability she will use it. Perhaps there's a 1% chance, perhaps 50%, perhaps 99%, perhaps it's totally unknown. "She may probably use it" suggests the speaker believes her using it is more probable than not, e.g. >50%.

Comment: In addition, colloquially "she probably may have a form" could well denote uncertainty, naively < 50%. It seems illogical, but I've heard such constructions to show the speaker isn't confident in what they are saying.

Answer (score 1):

As TRomano said above, one is enough but "may probably" isn't uncommon.

Prooffreader above commented "She may use it" gives no information about the probability, I disagree. Generally speaking, **may** is more of a ~30-70% chance, while **probably** is a 70+% chance (and **might** is <30%)

So "*she may have a form*" -> She could have one, she could not, neither would surprise you.

"*she probably has a form*" -> You believe she does most likely have a form

"*she probably may have a form*" -> I would not understand what they meant further than there is a possibility that she has a form (with no concept of the odds)

I think when someone says "may probably" they are usually backtracking in their head while talking, and initially intended to say "may" but changed their mind and added "probably" as an afterthought, realizing their statement was more likely than "may" would imply. I don't think people often say it intentionally, and I don't think I've ever seen it written (other than here ;) )